# How To Reference an Excel Table Cell by Row Number or Horizontal Header Using Table Notation?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to reference a single cell in a table, from *outside* the table, using square-bracket sheet-formula notation.

Something like:
[MyTable[MyField] 3]
or
[MyTable[MyField] 3:3]

-to reference the 3rd row of the MyField column, or:

[MyTable[MyField] MyRow]

-to reference the MyRow row (leftmost row-header) of the MyField column.

Needs to work from outside the table, ie can't use @ or #ThisRow.

Not looking for methods involving MATCH, INDEX, OFFSET, etc. Not looking for VBA methods. Just straightforward table-notation. Not looking for manually creating named ranges.

Why? Because, Tables  :)

Pre-2013 Excel.

(PS, didn't there used to be a way (pre-Tables) to reference cells by row and column headers? I think it was maybe called "auto-naming", or something like that.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

heh, well this works:

=Table1[Column2] 3:3

So that's progress :)

Just awesome would be a way to reference a row by the contents of left-most column.

Thx!

Comment: I believe you want to add 1 to whatever row # you are after.  1:1 returns an error.  2:2 returns the first row.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `index()` function as in:

```
index(MyTable[MyField], 3)
```

So you get row 3 from the column MyField in table MyTable.

Reference:
https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/116365-reference-a-single-cell-in-a-table-using-structured-referencing

Comment: thx, but i'm wondering how this is better than `Table1[Column2] 3:3`. Seems just more typing, plus using a function so performance may be worse.

Comment: I see a benefit: it will work even if table doesn't start on top row. The `3:3` notation will break if table doesn't start on sheet row 1.

Answer (score 5):

We can reuse the idea of the intersection operator (i.e. a space between two references) and improve it to have the relative row number of the targeted item in the table, referred to as `row_nb` here:

`=tbl[col] OFFSET(tbl[[#Headers],[col]],row_nb,)`

or just without intersection actually (cf. comment below):

`=OFFSET(tbl[[#Headers],[col]],row_nb,)`

E.g. `=Table1[Column2] OFFSET(Table1[[#Headers],[Column2]],2,)`

This way you do not depend on the position of the table in the worksheet. Well, it yields a more complicated formula where table name `tbl` and column name `col` appear twice. Here are some comments about it:

1. You can of course keep the `OFFSET(...)` part only. The downside is that the formula will never return any error if `row_nb` exceeds the actual number of line items in the table. It'll return e.g. just `0` if the cells below the table are empty.
2. Keeping a formula that throws an error when we refer to an off-table row, we can further improve it: make it "dynamic" by letting `tbl`, `col` and `row_nb` be parameters:

`=INDIRECT(tbl&"["&col&"]") OFFSET(INDIRECT(tbl&"[[#Headers],["&col&"]]"),row_nb,)`

Assuming that we've defined `tbl`, `col` and `row_nb` as named ranges. Or else just use cell addresses:

`=INDIRECT(A1&"["&A2&"]") OFFSET(INDIRECT(A1&"[[#Headers],["&A2&"]]"),A3,)`

I'm not a big fan of `INDIRECT` but in this case it really comes in handy to let the formula adapt to various tables, columns and line items.

Answer (score 0):

To handle tables that don't start at the first row of a worksheet, we can use the `ROW()` function. We can determine the first row of the data in the table with:

```
=ROW(myTable)
```

Using this and the `Indirect()` Function we can identify the first cell in a named column with

```
= myTable[myField] INDIRECT(ROW(myTable) & ":" & ROW(myTable))
```

The 3rd cell in that column would be:

```
= myTable[myField] INDIRECT(ROW(myTable)+3 & ":" & ROW(myTable)+3)
```