# Reference a range of columns of an excel table but for a specified row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Building on [this stackoverflow question (and it's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949642/how-to-reference-an-excel-table-cell-by-row-number-or-horizontal-header-using-ta), I am trying to reference a *range* of columns of an excel table, but I want to be able to control the row number. What would the syntax be?

For example, I tried to write the formula to only sum up the 2nd row of Table1:

I tried:

```
=SUM(Table1[[Column1]:[Column20]]2:2)
```

and

```
=SUM(Table1[[Column1]2:2:[Column20]2:2])
```

and they result in a warning that the syntax is wrong

Comment: What is your excel version? Do you have `SEQUENCE()` function?

Comment: @Harun24HR Excel 2016, no `SEQUENCE` available

Comment: This will work on Excel365 `=SUM(INDEX(Table1,2,SEQUENCE(,COUNTA(Table1[#Headers]))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to transpose full table then return column to sum. Try below-

```
=SUM(INDEX(TRANSPOSE(Table1),,2))
```

[image]